# How to use Installshield's built-in custom actions - They are not visible in execute sequence

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action, basic-msi, installshield-2016

There are two types of custom actions in installshield namely in-built and user-defined. I want to use installshield's built-in custom action named `ISSQLServerValidate` to check if it is possible connect to a given SQL Server instance or not using a user credential provided by the user. Detail of the in-built custom action `ISSQLServerValidate` is present [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/Ref-ISCustomActions.htm). I'm working on a Basic MSI project.

But when I go to either `User Interface` or `Execute` sequences I don't see it at all. I'm able to see whole lot of Standard actions (e.g. AppSearch, LaunchConditions)  and many other in-built custom actions (e.g. ISPreventDowngrade, setUserProfileNT etc.).

[image]

Why `ISSQLServerValidate` in-built custom action is not visible in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two factors that are likely to affect whether you can see the ISSQLServerValidate action.

1. There's a right-click option to show or hide the all the InstallShield actions. Since these are implementation details for options you have chosen in other views, it defaults to hiding these actions. However since your screen capture includes ISSetupFilesExtract and ISSetupFilesCleanup, I'm assuming you've already chosen to show these actions.
2. Most of these actions are only added once there's something for them to do. So ensure that you have added a connection (and maybe a script) in the SQL Scripts view.

Alternately, if you know how this action should be configured (for example if you can copy it from another project), it is safe to populate it and the related actions yourself. But I'd suggest just getting InstallShield to add it for you by adding the connection and/or script.

Comment: Both of your points apply to me. That `Show All Custom Actions` option is in the context menu when we right click the Custom Actions node (which I've not included in my screenshot) under `Behavior and Logic` -> `Custom Actions and Sequences`. After that, the moment I added a new SQL connection in `Server Configuration` -> `SQL Scripts` all SQL related built-in custom actions like `ISSQLServerInstall`, `ISSQLServerValidate` etc. popped-up. Thank you for the insight. This means there are many more built-in custom actions in InstallShield which get added only when we require a specific feature.